# How does JavaScript closure work in this case?

Tags: javascript, closures

How does JavaScript closure work in this case and to be more specific: what does the `(i)` at the end do?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(e);  
        }, 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

Also I'm trying to implement it in my code, and it seems I don't get it right

```
for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {

    var formID = document.forms["form-" + i];
    $(formID).bind("submit", validate);

    $(formID).bind("change", function(i){
        var divI = '#ind-' + i;
        $(divI).css("background-color","green");
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: If you want to learn more about closures here are some links that might help:

http://vimeo.com/1967261
http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Comment: The video is really great, thanx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a pattern used to create local scope around a variable. If this wasn't used then every call to `console.log(i)` would log the value of `i` (10) after the for loop finished.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // create new function
    (function(e) {
        // log each counter after 1 second.
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(e);  
        }, 1000);
    // execute it with the counter
    })(i); 
}
```

The above is the same as this.

```
function foobar(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(e);
    }, 1000);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (
        foobar
    )(i);
}
```

The real problem here is creating functions in a loop. don't do it :)

**Your code**

```
for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {

    var formID = document.forms["form-" + i];
    $(formID).bind("submit", validate);
    // create a full closure around the block of code
    (function() {
        $(formID).bind("change", function(i){
            var divI = '#ind-' + i;
            $(divI).css("background-color","green");
        })//(i); Don't call (i) here because your just trying to execute the 
        // jQuery element as a function. You can't do this, you need to wrap 
        // an entire function around it.
    })(i);
}
```

But that is wrong, you want to delegate this job to something else.

```
function makeGreen(form, i) {
    $(form).change(function() {
         $("#ind-"+i).css("background-color", "green");
    });
}

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    var formID = document.forms["form-" + i];
    $(formID).bind("submit", validate);
    // call a helper function which binds the change handler to the correct i
    makeGreen(formID, i);
}
```

If you want to get a bit clever you can get rid of these anonymous functions

```
function makeGreen() {
     var divId = $(this).data("div-id");
     $(divId).css("background-color", "green");
}

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    $(document.forms["form-" + i])
        .bind("submit", validate)
        // store i on the form element
        .data("div-id", "#ind-" + i)
        // use a single event handler that gets the divId out of the form.
        .change(makeGreen);
}
```

**Edit**

```
( // contain the function we create.
    function(parameterA) {
         window.alert(parameterA);
    }
) // this now points to a function
("alertMessage"); // call it as a function.
```

Is the same as

```
( // contain the window.alert function
    window.alert
) // it now points to a function
("alertMessage"); // call it as a function
```

Comment: thanx @Raynos, I see that, but I don't understand exactly how it works and how to implement it in my code (I edited the question), any suggestions? :)

Comment: +1 for *"The real problem here is creating functions in a loop. don't do it."* (assuming you're talking about the immediately invoked one). Perhaps add an example of a named function?

Comment: Personally I'm not so sure I dislike inline lambdas like that. It's a matter of style, I guess, and surely it's affected by experience with other functional languages. I see both sides of the argument, but I'm not sure which one wins :-)

Comment: @Pointy @T.J.Crowder I think the second example is better, rather then binding that data to the closure your binding it to the DOM element which is a far "cheaper" place for it to exist. @T.J.Crowder Also sorry for ruining your answer

Comment: @Raynos: I agree. And LOL, no worries, great answer.

Comment: @Raynos: Does your switch from `.data("divId", "#ind-" + i)` to `$(this).attr("div-id")` work? I just tested it and I get `undefined`. I'm pretty sure you'd need `$(this).data("divId")`. Right?

Comment: @Raynos,+1 for the breakdown, but there is no need to store the data anywhere, as it is part of element that handles the event. Just extract it from the `this.id`

Comment: @patrick_dw >_> thanks for spotting that. @Gaby good point. You can extract that `i` from the form id.

Comment: @TJ well if I've been working a lot in Clojure (or even Erlang), then the main problem I have with JavaScript lambdas is that the word "function" is so long :-)

Comment: @patrick dw: *"I'm definitely on the side of...avoiding closures (as handy as they are) whenever possible"* Of course, that means not writing any code in JavaScript, as **all** JavaScript functions are closures. ;-) @pointy: LOL

Comment: @T.J.Crowder closures are fine. (Awesome!), but creating them in a loop is a smell. That's just creating a bunch of new functions for no reason. You should be using `arr.forEach(function() { });` instead. It's a cleaner way to have that closure. (_.each or $.each if you care about IE support  ;))

Comment: @patrick dw, @Raynos: All JavaScript functions are closures, by specification. The most obvious aspect of this is that they close over the global execution context's variable binding object (sorry, *not* my terminology, that's [5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) spec-speak) -- which is a fancy way of saying they close over the global object. More (using the older 3rd edition spec terminology) here: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html

Comment: @Raynos: *"closures are fine. (Awesome!), but creating them in a loop is a smell"* Agreed (although I refuse to use that term), *unnecessarily* creating functions in a loop is a dumb thing to do. There's almost always a better solution.

Comment: @patrick dw, @Raynos thanx for the detailed answer! Yet there is one thing i don't understand - what is the `(i)` that comes at the end of the function in the example I've posted, what des it do?

Comment: @llyaD edited the question. The `(i)` just executes the question. Whether you place a anonymous function inside the brackets or a normal variable the calling of the function works the same way.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well I personally have not read the source in detail, but various reputable people claim that's what V8 does and I may be wrong in quoting them. And as awesome as the whole conversation is, the mods will clean this up because it's noise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm all for extended conversation in comments but [the mods @ Meta.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/how-do-our-moderators-and-community-members-feel-about-cleaning-up-comment-nois/1508#1508) disagree.

Comment: @Raynos: I see what you mean.

Comment: @Raynos, I still don't get it, the (i) is executing the function? are we talking about the (i) that appears before the closing brackets of th whole function..?

Comment: @llyaD were talk about `(function(i) { })(i);` Here you have a function that you create. Then you execute it. It's the same as `var a = function(i) { };(a)(i);`

Comment: @Raynos, no I'm only talking about the `(i)` at the end! `(function(i) { })**(i)**;` what does it do? I don't understand the syntax

Comment: @llyaD added an extra edit at the bottom. It just calls the function. just like `(alert)**("foo")**;` calls the function `alert`

Comment: ohhhh.. thanx.. :) never saw this syntax before

Answer (score 3):

Although not a direct answer to the closure question, here is my take on the issue.

I would re-write the logic to avoid the need for a closure (*as it seems overcomplicated for  the requirements*)

The fact that there is a pattern in the naming of the forms makes things really easy

```
$('form[id^="form-"]').submit(validate)
     .change(function(){
          var divI = '#ind-' + this.id.replace('form-','');
          $(divI).css("background-color","green");
     });
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/q8WxV/

Comment: thanx, but I don't understand `form[id^="form-"]` what does it do?

Comment: @IlyaD, it is the **[attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**. It means find all `forms` whose `id` starts with `"form-"`.